# How to use C++ ranges to implement numpy.ndindex?

Tags: c++, templates, range-v3

I'd like to implement equivalent of [`numpy.ndindex`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html) in C++. It is supposed to generate indices for a multi-dimensional array of specified dimensions.

Here is the implementation for a 2D array.

```
template <typename T>
inline auto NDIndex(T d0, T d1) {
  using namespace ranges;
  return views::cartesian_product(views::indices(d0), views::indices(d1));
}

// Usage
for (const auto[i1, i2] : NDIndex(5, 4)) {
  arr[i1][i2] = ...
}
```

I'd like to generalize it for an arbitrary number of dimensions without sacrificing the performance. I'm ok with using brace in the interface, e.g. `NDIndex({5, 4})`. I can think of multiple solutions but I'm not sure which would resolve this statically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`views::cartesian_product` is already variadic, you just need to expand a pack into it.

```
template <typename... Ts>
inline auto NDIndex(Ts ... ds) {
  using namespace ranges;
  return views::cartesian_product(views::indices(ds)...);
}

// Usage
int main() {
    for (const auto[i1, i2] : NDIndex(5, 4)) {
    }
    for (const auto[i1, i2, i3] : NDIndex(5, 4, 7)) {
    }
}
```

Comment: @bartop oops, stole your examples without changing them :p

Comment: btw, still does not compile :P

Answer (score 3):

This can be done this way

```
#include <range/v3/view/indices.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/cartesian_product.hpp>


template <unsigned... Ind>
constexpr inline auto NDIndex() {
  using namespace ranges;
  return views::cartesian_product(views::indices(Ind)...);
}


int main() {

    for (const auto[i1, i2] : NDIndex<5, 4>()) {
    }


    for (const auto[i1, i2, i3] : NDIndex<5, 4, 7>()) {
    }
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/iGy5vk)

Comment: I didn't mention that, but the limits can not be constexpr. I don't know them in advance.